# In distributed jmeter architecture I am stuck at 'Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jmeter, load-testing

**I have set up the environment as below**

1. All Servers have same version of jre.
2. All Servers have same version of jmeter.
3. All servers are in same subnet (x.x.x.227,x.x.x.228,x.x.x.229,x.x.x.230) with public IP.
4. The firewalls on the systems are turned off

**I have configured the below settings in master**

1. In /bin directory I have edited the file jmeter.properties, added IP slave machine as below:

   ## Remote hosts and RMI configuration:
2. remote_hosts=127.0.0.1(default in jmeter),x.x.x.227, x.x.x.228, x.x.x.229

   ## RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port)

server_port=1099

**I have done the below Configuration in slave machines**

1. Added the following to server (Slave) jmeter.properties:

   ## On the server(s)

set server_port=1234
start rmiregistry with port 1234

**Once the configuration part is done**

1. Started jmeter server in slave systems using following command
   ./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.227 (slave IP)
2. Now started the Jmeter engine on Master(x.x.x.230).
3. Started Jmeter on master machine (GUI)
4. Created test plan--> (added tread group , samplers and required listners)
5. Started jmeter test script with following command
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -R x.x.x.227 -l test1.jtl

After that the message 'Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445' appears and I am suck here. test1.jtl file is also not created and I don't see any responses.

**Meanwhile I get the below response in slave server**
 Starting the test on host x.x.x.227 @ Wed Mar 29 11:10:24 IST 2017 (1490766024242)
Finished the test on host x.x.x.227 @ Wed Mar 29 11:10:32 IST 2017 (1490766032637)

It's visible from above that the test session lasted for 8-9 seconds and it always the same for any duration that mention in the testscript and I am stuck with the shutdown message on master server.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: What did you see in your JMeter logs? You can set `true` for this `jmeterengine.force.system.exit` in your properties file which will force NON-GUI JVM to exit after test end.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't open Firewall ports between jmeter-server machines and the client servers.

So they are not able to notify client that the test has ended.

Set this "client.rmi.localport" property to a port of your choice and open it

Answer (score 0):

Please check also the space. I solve this issue after removing some unused lo